# How to compare two directories with similar folders / files

Tags: unix

How to compare two directories with similar folders / files. I would like to find the differences between files (binary, ascii) in the respective folders. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `diff -arq folder1 folder2` or `diff -r folder1 folder2`